# Java Node.setTextContent((myString)) converts < and > to &lt; and &gt;

Tags: java, xml, string, nodes, xmlnode

I am trying to use `setNodeContent` to set the value if node which contains child nodes. I have verified that my String has correct tags but when it writes to node using `setNodeContent` it is not retaining the tags.

`myString` = WaterItalics

`Node.setTextContent`((String)) ==> Water<ital>

Expected `Node.setTextContent`((String)) ==> WaterItalics

Comment: Is the code you posted java code? It doesn't compile for me. What am I missing?

Comment: Its not a complete code. I am just trying to show how I used setTextContent by passing a String

Comment: The formatter might have replaced my text. myString = Water<ital>, 

I am trying to use setNodeContent to set the value if node which contains child nodes. I have verified that my String has correct tags but when it writes to node using setNodeContent it is not retaining the tags.

myString = Water< somenode > 

Node.setTextContent((String)) ==> Water&lt;ital&gt;

Comment: And `Node` is of what type? Which API are you using? In general, you cannot add XML as text. You need to use the API to build the document tree. If it is text you want to add, then the behavior is correct as `<>` are reserved characters and cannot appear in text nodes. Thus they get entity encoded: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML

Comment: Maybe you should read [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)